# First-order intuitionistic logic question

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

I know that if $A$ is a theorem of classical propositional logic, then $\neg \neg A$ is a theorem of intuitionistic propositional logic. I read in a previous question I asked long ago, that the corresponding statement for first order logic is false. Can someone give an explicit counterexample $A$?

Comment: The mentioned answer is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1315186/28111).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \neg \neg \forall x(p(x)\lor \neg p(x)) $$
is not a theorem of pure intuitionistic first-order logic.

Namely, it is false in the [Kripke model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Intuitionistic_first-order_logic) with a countable infinity of worlds
$$ w_0 \le w_1 \le w_2 \le \cdots \le w_n \le \cdots $$
where the individuals in each world are $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, and $p(n)$ is true from world $w_n$ onwards.

Then $p(n)\lor \neg p(n)$ is *false* in $w_{n-1}$, and therefore $\forall x(p(x)\lor \neg p(x))$ is *false everywhen*, so its double negation is equally false.